# iTunes API and HTTPS

Tags: json, api, ssl, https, itunes

I wondered if anyone here could give some clarfication on wehther the iTunes and Flickr API's can be called up via https. This is for a facebook app.

These two API's are being blocked in the app due to non https call ups via JSon. I tried a few fixes but iTunes and Flickr do not seem to offer https for their API's. Am I wasting my time?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The iTunes Search API just got support for https.  You can find the announcement on the affiliate resources site here:
http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/secure-links-to-itunes---content-and-tools.html